# mkinitramfs failed to determine device for /

Tags: debian, debian-stretch, initramfs

I'm following this tutorial : [Create a Custom Debian Live](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/)  (it's not the first time) but this time it doesn't work when I'm trying to install linux-image-amd64 live-boot systemd-sysv in chroot environment.

Error is :

```
mkinitramfs: failed to determine device for /
mkinitramfs: workaround is MODULES=most, check
grep -r MODULES /etc/initramfs-tools
```

It's during the update-initramfs. When I run it alone, it returns the same error. The grep command returns :

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.con:MODULES=most
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/driver-policy:MODULES=dep
```

The distribution is Debian Stretch installed from minimal (netinstall) in kernel 4.9.0-6.

When I was in 4.9.0-4 or 4.9.0-5 I've never had this problem. Maybe it's with the 4.9.0-6 ?

Any solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/driver-policy to replace

```
MODULES=dep
```

by

```
MODULES=most
```

and it "works". There are many lines with "W: possible missing firmware ..." but it updates the initrd correctly and I can boot my Live environment.